# Live Filtering in DataGrid using TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Ihave a textbox and a DataGrid. When I type in something in textbox, I want to filter the data in DataGrid.

I have done that with the below mentioned code:

In XAML:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupsViewSource" Source="{Binding Groups, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="GroupName"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<DataGrid Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupsViewSource}}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
          SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
          EnableRowVirtualization="False" VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="False" RowEditEnding="DataGrid_RowEditEnding">

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Group Name" Width="*" SortMemberPath="GroupName">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Parent Group" Width="*" SortMemberPath="ParentID">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentID, Converter={StaticResource parentIDToGroupNameConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ParentGroupsViewSource}}" 
                              DisplayMemberPath="GroupName"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding ParentID, Converter={StaticResource parentIDToGroupNameConverter}}" SelectedValuePath="GroupName"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EditButton}" Height="35" Width="35" 
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsInEdit, 
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityInverseConverter}}" 
                                Click="EditSaveButton_Click" 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.EditCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnSave" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SaveButton}" Height="35" Width="35" 
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsInEdit, 
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                                Click="EditSaveButton_Click"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" Width="70" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DeleteButton}" Height="35" Width="35"
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsInEdit, 
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityInverseConverter}}" 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CancelButton}" Height="35" Width="35" 
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsInEdit, 
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                                                     Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.CancelCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>

<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SearchGroupName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

In CodeBehind:

```
private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    var a = e.Item.GetType().GetProperty("GroupName");
    if (a != null)
    {
        if (_viewModel.SearchGroupName != "")
        {
            var s = a.GetValue(e.Item, null);
            if (s != null)
                e.Accepted = s.ToString().Contains(_viewModel.SearchGroupName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            else
                e.Accepted = false;
        }
        else
            e.Accepted = true;
    }
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
ERPLiteDBContext db = new ERPLiteDBContext();

public ListViewModel()
{
    Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>(db.Groups);
    SearchGroupName = "";
}

private string _searchGroupName;
public string SearchGroupName
{
    get
    {
        return _searchGroupName;
    }
    set
    {
        _searchGroupName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SearchGroupName");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Group> _groups;
public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups
{
    get
    {
        return _groups;
    }
    set
    {
        _groups = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Groups");
    }
}
```

The above code works. But for above code to work, I have to type-in something into the textBox, then click on the header of the DataGrid to sort it. So, in short above code does not provide live filtering. I would like to filter my data when I type-in something in TextBox......

Comment: I would not mix filtering and sorting here. In your TextBox TextChanged handler, You could retrieve the DataGrid's CollectionViewSource and set the filter delegate. That should work.

Comment: I don't understand filter delegate. Can you give a code example or any links?

Answer (score 2):

So the filtering in your code is actually a follow-up from sorting. To perform filtering whenever you like, I suggest following, making small changes to your viewmodels:

`Group` knows wether itself should be filtered or not. It has a `IsHidden` property:

```
public class Group // actually a viewmodel
{
    public bool IsHidden
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
...
}
```

`IsHidden` is set for each member in the collection, each time the Text changes. The `CollectionViewSource` checks this property:

```
private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // reset first to keep continious filtering
    Groups.ToList().ForEach(i => i.IsHidden = false);

    foreach (var filteredGroup in Groups.Where(vm => vm.Name == _viewModel.SearchGroupName))
    {
        filteredGroup.IsHidden = true;
    }
    ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_dataGrid.ItemsSource);
    if (cv != null)
    {
        // filter the Groups collection
        cv.Filter = (vm as Group) => vm.IsHidden == false;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, It doesn't filter any data.

Comment: I have left the idea of filtering, instead I select the item that starts with the text entered in the textbox and say scrollInToView......... Thanks for any help.

Comment: Above code should shrink the Itemssource and therefore sure it filters data. It may be that the filtercondition or the flag should be toggled, which depends on what you are targeting with the text input (show or hide).  Anyway could you post your solution then ? Others may try to answer your question, not seeing your comment.